# How could I compare these database values in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

So a user selects from a drop down list a value. I take this value, put it into a variable, then select from the database the ID value of that table A holding the selected value also.

So now I'm trying to use that ID value to get to a many-to-many relationship table that has the selected value from table A to a different table B. The many-to-many relationship table has both IDs. How can I compare this using PHP?

So it would be like:

```
$A = $_POST['a'];
$sql = "SELECT a, aID from TABLEA WHERE a = $A";
```

What do I do then to compare the aID with the many-to-many relationships table, then get the other ID in that table and then take that ID to get values from table B?

Comment: Please don't start sentences with a conjunctive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a join in your SQL:

```
SELECT table_b.* FROM ab_association
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = ab_association.b_id
WHERE ab_association.a_id = $specified_id;
```

That assumes that your many-to-many join table is called `ab_association` and has two columns, one called `a_id` that corresponds to `table_a.id`, and `b_id` that corresponds to `table_b.id`.

Update: I removed the table name aliases since they seem to be confusing you.

Another Update: In PHP, here's how you would do that (sans business logic):

```
<?

// connect to db here
$a_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['a_id']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT table_b.* FROM ab_association LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.id = ab_association.b_id WHERE ab_association.a_id = $a_id;");

// in your view/template
while(false !== (mysql_fetch_object($result))) {
  // build your output for each row
}

?>
```

Comment: What's the b.* supposed to represent? I'm sort of confused here, could you show this code with my code in the order you're trying to communicate? It doesn't look like I'm comparing aID here?

Comment: It's an alias for `table_b`. Note the `table_b b`. That's a shorthand way of saying `table_b AS b`.

Comment: I'm sort of confused here, could you show this code with my code in the order you're trying to communicate? It doesn't look like I'm comparing aID here?

Comment: So if my table B was called Batteries I would have the first line as SELECT Batteries.* FROM the many-to-many table?

Comment: Bingo. You'll reference `Batteries` with the `LEFT JOIN Batteries on Batteries.id = many_to_many_table.b_id` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
LEFT JOIN ab_association ON table_a.aID = ab_association.aID
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.bID = ab_association.bID
WHERE table_a.a = $A
```

Notes:

- I used some underscores in tablenames, so table_a instead of TABLEA (just like Coreyward did) to distinguish between sql and names
- You should specify the columns you need instead of 'SELECT *' if many columns aren't needed
- You can use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN if you want get an empty recordset when no match in the many-to-many is found. (Using a LEFT JOIN has the advantage you still have access to the columns in table_A)
- it is never wise to use $_POST-vars directly in your queries, this is a serious security risk (SQL injection.)

Comment: Wait, what values here am I getting? I see select * from table_a but I'm trying to basically connect table A to table B to get values from table B. I'd then want to display table B values as a list on another webpage. Any advice on how to do that?

Comment: This is the same thing I did, but since he's not actually trying to get the data for `table_a`, we can skip that table all together, going straight for all of the associated items in `table_b`.

Comment: @Coreyward: The main difference is that as I understand it, the OP is not getting the aID but some other value in table A. Then you need to include table A in the join.

Comment: Gotcha. You may be right, and if so, high-five for gleaning that. :)